# python creating a structure

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to perform some operations on the data from a file. I have managed to load the file using np.loadtxt

```
data = np.loadtxt('original_data.txt', dtype={'names': ('fileName', 'object_no', 'instance', 'tilt', 'pan_no', 'panValue'),'formats': ('S70', 'f5', 'f5', 'f5', 'f5', 'S5')})
```

I figured out that I can access the individual column using `name_new= data['fileName']`. (1-D array)

What is the best way to have it in a structure (matlab equivalent) format so that I can access each of the elements from a single array.

`original_data`:

```
[ ('RGBD_Crop_file/hand_towel_5_2_260_crop.png', 23.0, 5.0, 2.0, 260.0, 'NA')
('RGBD_Crop_file/lightbulb_1_4_76_crop.png', 28.0, 1.0, 4.0, 76.0, '132.3') 
('RGBD_Crop_file/apple_2_2_97_crop.png', 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 97.0, 'NA')
('RGBD_Crop_file/stapler_6_2_35_crop.png', 46.0, 6.0, 2.0, 35.0, 'NA')  
('RGBD_Crop_file/toothpaste_2_2_119_crop.png', 49.0, 2.0, 2.0, 119.0, 'NA') 
('RGBD_Crop_file/garlic_4_2_201_crop.png', 20.0, 4.0, 2.0, 201.0, '301.9')]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Python dictionary or list or Object can be a good choice.

Comment: Please elaborate on ```access each of the elements from a single array```.  Also, please post a few rows of the data - maybe shorten the ```filename``` field a bit.

Comment: Read each line from file and convert each line into an entry for the Python list. How you convert line to an entry will depends on your data.

Comment: [ ('RGBD_Crop_file/hand_towel_5_2_260_crop.png', 23.0, 5.0, 2.0, 260.0, 'NA')
 ('RGBD_Crop_file/lightbulb_1_4_76_crop.png', 28.0, 1.0, 4.0, 76.0, '132.3')
 ('RGBD_Crop_file/apple_2_2_97_crop.png', 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 97.0, 'NA') ...,
 ('RGBD_Crop_file/stapler_6_2_35_crop.png', 46.0, 6.0, 2.0, 35.0, 'NA')
 ('RGBD_Crop_file/toothpaste_2_2_119_crop.png', 49.0, 2.0, 2.0, 119.0, 'NA')
 ('RGBD_Crop_file/garlic_4_2_201_crop.png', 20.0, 4.0, 2.0, 201.0, '301.9')]

Comment: That is the format of the text in the file?

Comment: It isn't clear (to me, anyway) what you want.  You can access the first record using, for example, `record0 = data[0]`.  The fields of that record are accessed using the same notation as for the the full array, e.g. `filename0 = record0['fileName']; tilt0 = record0['tilt']`.

Comment: `loadtxt` has given you a `structured array` - a `numpy` array with fields.  This is close to the `MATLAB` structure.  However the `scipy` code that loads `.mat` files, puts the structures into Python dictionaries.  And MATLAB into Python lists.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want is something like this:

```
with open("filename") as f:
    items = [line.split() for line in f]
```

If you want to evaluate each value, rather than having all strings, you can use:

```
    items = [map(eval, line.split()) for line in f]
```

Comment: Thanks..looks like I don't need to load it as a numpy array

Comment: Pablo's `items` are not an array, just a list of lists.  You can't do many MATLAB like operations on a list.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your 'original_data', I think your `data` array prints like:

```
array([ ('RGBD_Crop_file/hand_towel_5_2_260_crop.png', 23.0, 5.0, 2.0, 260.0, 'NA'),
       ('RGBD_Crop_file/lightbulb_1_4_76_crop.png', 28.0, 1.0, 4.0, 76.0, '132.3'),
       ('RGBD_Crop_file/apple_2_2_97_crop.png', 0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 97.0, 'NA'),
       ('RGBD_Crop_file/stapler_6_2_35_crop.png', 46.0, 6.0, 2.0, 35.0, 'NA'),
       ('RGBD_Crop_file/toothpaste_2_2_119_crop.png', 49.0, 2.0, 2.0, 119.0, 'NA'),
       ('RGBD_Crop_file/garlic_4_2_201_crop.png', 20.0, 4.0, 2.0, 201.0, '301.9')], 
      dtype=[('fileName', 'S70'), ('object_no', '<f4'), ('instance', '<f4'), ('tilt', '<f4'), ('pan_no', '<f4'), ('panValue', 'S5')])
```

It is an array with 6 elements, shape `(6,)`, and complex `dtype` (which you specified).

As you note you can access a single field ('column') like:

```
data['fileName']
```

A row or element can be viewed with

```
data[3]
```

It too has the complex dtype, though it displays as a simple `tuple`.

You could do math across a couple of fields, like:

```
data['tilt']*data['pan_no']
```

or across the values of one field:

```
np.mean(data['tilt'])
```

What else do you want to do?  How does this differ from accessing the data in a `MATLAB` structure?

Answer (score 0):

I think named tuples are good for this kind of thing:

```
import collections
DataRow = collections.namedtuple( "DataRow", ['column1','column2'] )
d = DataRow( "data in column1", "data in column2" )
```

In your application, you'd create an array of named tuples.  I believe that named tuples provide for the "struct" functionality you're asking for.